# Laravel 4 advanced wheres

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

I have my query working perfectly in mySQL, however am struggling to use the advanced wheres inside the laravel query builder.

Can anyone assist in converting this at all?

So far I have:

LARAVEL

```
$start_request = '2014-12-18 09:00';
$end_request = '2014-12-18 10:00';

$events=  DB::table('events')
          ->where('hotel_id', 4)
          ->orWhere(function($query)
                {
                    $query->where($start_request, '<=', 'start_time')
                              ->where($end_request, '>', 'start_time');
                })
            ->orWhere(function($query)
                 {
                     $query->where($start_request, '>=', 'start_time')
                                ->where($end_request, '<', 'end_time');
                 })
            ->get();
```

mySQL

```
SELECT id, title, description, start_time, end_time FROM events where hotel_id = 4 and (('2014-12-18 09:00' <= start_time and '2014-12-18 10:00' > start_time) 
       or ('2014-12-18 09:00' >= start_time and '2014-12-18 10:00' < end_time));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
$start_request = '2014-12-18 09:00';
$end_request = '2014-12-18 10:00';

$events=  DB::table('events')
          ->where('hotel_id', 4)
          ->where(function($query) use($start_request, $end_request) {
                    $query->where(function($subquery) use($start_request, $end_request){
                        $subquery->where('start_time', '>=', $start_request)
                                 ->where('start_time', '<', $end_request);
                    });
                    $query->orWhere(function($subquery1) use($start_request, $end_request) {
                        $subquery1->where('start_time', '<=', $start_request)
                                ->where('end_time', '>', $end_request);
                    });

            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: I'm getting 'Undefined variable: start_request'

Comment: Ok, that's fine, I've updated my answer. I'm sorry but I can't test it at the moment on my env.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you so much for your help. It's really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the job:

```
$start_request = '2014-12-18 09:00';
$end_request = '2014-12-18 10:00';

$events = DB::table('events')
    ->where('hotel_id', 4)
    ->where(function ($q) use ($start_request, $end_request) {
        $q->where(function ($query) use ($start_request, $end_request) {
            $query->where($start_request, '<=', 'start_time')
                ->where($end_request, '>', 'start_time');
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($start_request, $end_request) {
            $query->where($start_request, '>=', 'start_time')
                ->where($end_request, '<', 'end_time');
        });
    })
    ->select('id', 'title', 'description', 'start_time', 'end_time')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you Marcin, your adaption is most helpful